# Adding JS into the html (SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to **add a little js code into the html of an external webpage** using chrome console. I would use iMacros but it has very limited capabilities for my needs.

This is just an example:

```
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = 
"<script type='text/javascript'>
alert(\"yes\");
</script>";
```

When I run it, it says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". Is there any workaround or how can I do what I want to do?

Comment: *"HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted via `innerHTML` should not execute."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

Comment: Thanks. I solved it with document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML and document.write :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include line breaks in a string without escaping.  Either put it on one line:

```
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"yes\");</script>";
```

or escape with a backslash before the newline

```
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = 
"<script type='text/javascript'>\
alert(\"yes\");\
</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't give any error but still it doesn't alert. I mean the JS code doesn't work after I insert it into the HTML. How can I make it work? I tried setInterval.

Comment: @noarm: *"HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted via `innerHTML` should not execute."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in single line

```
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = 
"<script type='text/javascript'> alert(\"yes\");</script>";
```

### OR

Use `\` to make it multi-line variable

```
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = 
"<script type='text/javascript'>\
alert(\"yes\");\
</script>";
```

### OR

Use simple string concatenation

```
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = 
    "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
    "alert(\"yes\");" +
    "</script>";
```